# use locate command to find only files, excluding symbolic links and directories

Tags: locate

I'm trying to use locate to find any files on my system that contain the word 'Jaynes'.      Unfortunately there's a symbolic link called Jaynes that points to a directory.       I want to exclude all symbolic links and directories from my locate search.      Obviously, I can do this with `find` but it's slower.

To be specific, the output from this command in my bash script

```
ls -al `/usr/bin/locate -i Jaynes`
```

is

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 simon simon     80 Aug 10  2016 /home/simon/LOCALSVN/ward/trunk/literature/Jaynes/JaynesBook.html
lrwxrwxrwx 1 simon simon     49 Oct 24  2016 /home/simon/research/Monash/Ward/literature/Jaynes -> /home/simon/LOCALSVN/ward/trunk/literature/Jaynes

/home/simon/LOCALSVN/ward/trunk/literature/Jaynes:
total 1352
drwxr-xr-x 2 simon simon   4096 Aug 10  2016 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 simon simon   4096 Oct 21  2016 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 simon simon     80 Aug 10  2016 JaynesBook.html
```

What I'm trying to do is eliminate the reference to the symbolic link (the second line) and also to the lines below which follow the symbolic link, leaving *only* the first line, which is a real file.

Thanks very much for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`locate` itself does not have an option to filter out links (it can only follow or not follow links. You can filter out links using something else:

```bsh
locate() {
    command locate -0 "$@" |      # print filenames separated by \0
      while IFS= read -rd '' f    # read filenames separated by \0
      do
          [[ -l "$f" ]] ||        # test for links
             printf "%s\n" "$f"
      done
}
```

Save this in your `.bashrc`; then in a new shell, `locate -i Jaynes` will not list links.